# Detect full version internet explorer with javascript?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to detect the full version of internet explorer.

```
navigator.appVersion
```

navigator.appVersion only gives the major version, for example 9.0
But it doesn't show 9.0.8112.1642...

Comment: I don't think so with just JavaScript. Would probably have to use something like an ActiveX control and read it from the registry as that's the only place I know where it's stored but I could be wrong

Comment: It would be rather insecure wouldn't it? If you could gather the exact version, you could easily target attacks for known vulnerabilities.

Comment: "ActiveX control and read it from the registry" - How?

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately you do not have access to the IE build number in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

There is a solution for this below, however only works in 32bit version of Windows:
http://www.pinlady.net/PluginDetect/IE/

```
var e, obj = document.createElement("div"), 
    verIEfull = null; // Full IE version [string/null]

try{ 
    obj.style.behavior = "url(#default#clientcaps)";

    verIEfull = obj.getComponentVersion("{89820200-ECBD-11CF-8B85-00AA005B4383}","componentid").replace(/,/g,".");
}catch(e){};
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [microsoft development website](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537509%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

```
function getInternetExplorerVersion()
// Returns the version of Internet Explorer or a -1
// (indicating the use of another browser).
{
  var rv = -1; // Return value assumes failure.
  if (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer')
  {
    var ua = navigator.userAgent;
    var re  = new RegExp("MSIE ([0-9]{1,}[\.0-9]{0,})");
    if (re.exec(ua) != null)
      rv = parseFloat( RegExp.$1 );
  }
  return rv;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't give any more information compared to `navigator.appVersion` that the OP already said wasn't what he wanted.

Answer (score 0):

```
 navigator.userAgent;
```

Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; InfoPath.2)

One possibility is that compare .NET versions with IE minor versions, if we get somewhere that table on microsoft IE documentation.

Comment: "One possibility is that compare .NET versions with IE minor versions, if we get somewhere that table on microsoft IE documentation." - How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I'd do this:

```
var IEVersion = 0;
if( window.attachEvent && /MSIE ([\d\.]+)/.exec(navigator.appVersion) ){
    IEVersion = parseInt( RegExp.$1 );
}
```

It's compact and dodges spoofed UserAgent strings by checking the event model is actually IE first:

Comment: Does not give a full version either. Not better than: navigator.appVersion