# Is it possible to detect full Internet Explorer 11 build version using a script?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, browser, cross-browser

I need to distinguish between Internet Explorer's builds 11.0.9600.XXXX and 11.0.10240.XXXX in my website. I tried simple JavaScript/Angular/JQuery plugins but they only give the major (11) and minor version (0).

The ActiveX solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17420757/5501520) is not working for me. Moreover, it is specific to 32 bit versions of Windows.

So far I haven't found a solution to this. Is it possible to do?

**If not, is there a reliable link from Microsoft confirming that this is not possible?**

Answer (score 0):

If it's those two particular builds you're looking for, detecting the OS might be enough (Windows NT 6.3 vs Windows NT 10.0).

For anyone wondering why this would be necesary: I did notice a difference in how cookies in iframes are handled, so I made a demo page to demonstrate it: http://lakora.us/cookietest